# Vanilla Javascript, how to read local JSON file

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am new to javascript and I am trying to read a JSON file using javascript, but I do not know how to access data from the promise result. I have my data in a .json file call Data.json and I am using fetch inside in a promise to load the JSON file and return the result. How can I get the data from the promise result?

**Data in JSON file**

```
{
 "data": {
   "reviewer": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "susan smith",
    "job": "web developer",
    "text": "I'm baby meggings twee health goth +1. Bicycle rights tumeric chartreuse before they sold out chambray pop-up. Shaman humblebrag pickled coloring book salvia hoodie, cold-pressed four dollar toast everyday carry"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "anna johnson",
    "job": "web designer",
    "text": "Helvetica artisan kinfolk thundercats lumbersexual blue bottle. Disrupt glossier gastropub deep v vice franzen hell of brooklyn twee enamel pin fashion axe.photo booth jean shorts artisan narwhal."
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "peter jones",
    "job": "intern",
    "text": "Sriracha literally flexitarian irony, vape marfa unicorn. Glossier tattooed 8-bit, fixie waistcoat offal activated charcoal slow-carb marfa hell of pabst raclette post-ironic jianbing swag."
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "bill anderson",
    "job": "the boss",
    "text": "Edison bulb put a bird on it humblebrag, marfa pok pok heirloom fashion axe cray stumptown venmo actually seitan. VHS farm-to-table schlitz, edison bulb pop-up 3 wolf moon tote bag street art shabby chic. "
  }
]
}}
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
const data = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
fetch('./Data.json')
    .then(respond => {
        resolve(respond.json())
    }).catch(err => {
        reject(err)
 })
})

console.log(data)
```

When I run the code, I got this in the console.

[image]

Comment: Don't [create a new promise](https://runnable.com/blog/common-promise-anti-patterns-and-how-to-avoid-them) just to wrap `fetch`. `fetch` *already returns a promise*.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`fetch()` returns a `Promise`, so you don't need to create one yourself. `Promise` returned by `fetch` fulfills with a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object on which you need to call [.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) method to get the actual data. This method also returns a `Promise`, so you need to chain another `then()` method call.

```
fetch('./Data.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

For details, see:

- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: This should be  " .catch(err => console.log(err));"  not console.log(error). Other than that works great.

Comment: @MollyJ thanks for pointing out the typo. I had to look at the code more than once to detect the problem.

Comment: i did the same but it does not log into console
can i have the data set into a var?

Comment: Question: does fetch work directly on **Local files** (no server involved) or a **server** is needed to interact with?

Comment: @willywonka JavaScript in the browser can't read the file system. The `fetch` function can request the server for the file. The server can be local or remote.